# CDI producer that handles any qualifier

Tags: java, dependency-injection, cdi

Can I create a producer method that handles *any* arbitrary qualifier?  i.e.: even qualifiers I'm not "aware-of" at design time?

The challenge is that I want to create an injectable simplification of an outside-developed injectable component.  The tough part is: I want my simplification to support all the qualifier annotations of the original component.  And to be future-proof, I want to be agnostic to those qualifiers.

My plan was to have my producer dynamically create the original component using qualifiers passed to my producer method's `InjectionPoint`, but CDI isn't matching my producer with the original component's qualifiers.  Is there a way to declare my producer to handle arbitrary qualifiers?  I don't think `@Decorator` is an option, since I want to wrap the original component without exposing its interface.

Comment: You might be interested in https://lairdnelson.wordpress.com/2017/02/11/dynamic-cdi-producer-methods/, or an approach like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to write a portable extension that:

1. is notified upon the appearance of any `Set` of qualifiers that qualify non-vetoed injection scenarios (observing `ProcessInjectionPoint` will get you most of the way there, if not all the way)
2. at `AfterBeanDiscovery` time, for each `Set` of harvested qualifiers, adds beans that produce the qualified things

…or something of this nature.

To do (2), you may just want to use the `BeanConfigurator` stuff, i.e.:

```
private void addMyBeans(@Observes AfterBeanDiscovery event) {
  event.addBean()
    .types(...)
    .qualifiers(harvestedQualifiers)
    .scope(...)
    .produceWith(i -> new Frobnicator()) // create whatever it is you're making
    .disposeWith(...)
```

Comment: Good answer!  I've unfortunately come to find my platform doesn't support CDI Portable Extensions (Quarkus: although they offer a hokey proprietary reimagining of this capability, it's not something I want to pursue).  Regardless, this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

The question is too generic to provide a direct answer.

It looks like what you are trying to do should be implemented as a *CDI portable extension*.

The extension SPI provides hooks that can dynamically modify both qualifiers and producers.

The *InjectionTarget* is the abstraction of the concept you are trying to apply, see this documentation https://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#_wrapping_an_injectiontarget

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you start with plain old Java interface design?

What is methods signature that is in use?

Do you know how to do without CDI with `new` ?

If you don't that taking about CDI (Contexts and Dependency Injection) only complicates. Why not Spring? etc

The best design does not depend on any framework.

P.S. And please share real code.